# Array Values for SetText in Android from PHP

Tags: java, php, android, arrays

This is my java code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String products) {
    this.inv_title.setText(products);
}
```

The thing is that *String products* is an array from **PHP/server**. So when I `setText` it, the entire Array shows on `EditText` field.

Please show me howw I am supposed to do this as in `setText` with the corressponding array value. Whenever I change *String products* to *Array products* my java encounters an error.

P.S. I am new to do this so my error could be very simple.

Thanks

Comment: What you want to show in `inv_title` from products. And `products` is `JsonArray`?? because the code you have posted showing it as `String`.

Comment: i guess product is json, kindly show what it is

Answer (score 0):

Well, edit your `onPostExecute` parameter to an ArrayList.

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList products) {
this.inv_title.setText(products.get(0));

\\change the index of the arraylist for your needs

}
```